# How do I include formatting (colour) when I link cells between sheets in an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

I have two sheets which have some linked cells using `='Master'!cell`.

In the master these cells have a background colour, which is sometimes manually changed when the cell is updated.

Is it possible to automatically update the colour formatting of the copied sheet when the master is updated?

Comment: Nope, but you can try to color both sheets with the same rule of [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). UPDATE: Ok, maybe you could do it using VBA, but i think it's easier to do it with Conditional Formatting indeed.

Comment: With VBA you can do an on worksheet change event, then change cell background colours: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Interior.Color = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1").Interior.Color Adjust as required. This will only monitor when a value has changed and not a background colour, so the colour would have to manulaly changed than a value changed on the sheet for it to work. if you think this would work for you, let us know and someone will help.

Comment: I have found the VBA code to be able to link cells to change colour within the same sheet. I'm no expert on VBA, could anyone help with adapting the below to reference a cell in another sheet? Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Range("C5").Interior.Color = Me.Range("A5").Interior.Color
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to help you with your comment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' change the worksheet names to match your worksheets and also the cell references    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Interior.Color = worksheets("Master").Range("A5").Interior.Color

End Sub
```

if you want to make changes when a particular cell is changed on your worksheet then you can target a particular cell or range:

```
  Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Interior.Color = Worksheets("Master").Range("A5").Interior.Color

    End If

 End Sub
```